# How to install custom version of symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I want to install specific version of symfony with composer:

```
 composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton blog 4.2.9
 composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:4.2.9 blog
```

In --help there are :

```
php composer.phar create-project vendor/project target-directory [version]
php composer.phar create-project vendor/project:version target-directory
```

But I get an error :

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                           
  Could not find package symfony/website-skeleton with version 4.2.9.
```

Although it exists https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-4-2-9-released

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. Check https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/website-skeleton
You must request for exact version eg. 4.2.9.1